# Append function in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, append, addition

I need help for my project. I have an array that look like this?

```
rndm = [[0 1]
        [0 0]
        [0 0]
        [0 1]]
```

Now, I want to add `par_1 = [[1 0]], par_2 = [[0 0], ch1 = [[1 1]], and ch2 = [[0 1]]` to rndm.

My code looks like this:

```
new_rndm = []
new_rndm.append(par_1)
new_rndm.append(par_2)
new_rndm.append(ch1)
new_rndm.append(ch2)
# add them to rndm
rndm = numpy.append(rndm, [new_rndm])
print(rndm)
```

The output gives me something like this:

```
rndm = [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
```

What I am expecting as my out put is:

```
rndm = [[0 1]
        [0 0]
        [0 0]
        [0 1]
        [1 0]
        [0 0]
        [1 1]
        [0 1]]
```

I think the problem is that append cannot be used in arrays. If correct, anyone help me what other function I could try? If not, kindly educate me. I am very much willing to learn. Thank you!

Comment: Is it a numpy array ?

Comment: @Sushanth rndm is an array.

Comment: we are able to see it is an array but is it python ``nested list`` or a ``numpy array`` ?

Comment: @Sushanth my bad, it is a numpy array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.append(<array>, <elem to append>, axis=0)`

```
rndm = np.array([[0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1]])

par_1 = [[1, 0]]; par_2 = [[0, 0]]; ch1 = [[1, 1]]; ch2 = [[0, 1]]

rndm = np.append(rndm, par_1, axis=0)
rndm = np.append(rndm, par_2, axis=0)
rndm = np.append(rndm, ch1, axis=0)
rndm = np.append(rndm, ch2, axis=0)
```

---

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

---

**Edit:**

**Reshape:**

```
x = np.array([2,1])
y = x.reshape(-1,1) # <------------ you have to do this
x.shape, y.shape
```

---

```
((2,), (2, 1))
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer! But why is it that I am getting an error trying this solution? Error is: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Comment: What `numpy` version do you use?  I use `1.18.4`

Comment: Are you using the whole code or some part of it. Because I am not getting any error.

Comment: I am using the same version of numpy. This is just a part of my code. rndm is generated randomly as well as par_1 and the others.

Comment: check their dimenision by using `.shape`. There is  dimension issue with your randomly genereated solution.

Comment: shapes are for rndm = (4, 2), for par_1 and the others = (2, ). Does this mean there should be a change for rndm?

Comment: This (2, ) is the cause of this issue. reshape it to (2,1)

Comment: is this where the reshape function is used? Sorry, I am still new to python. There are functions that I haven't been used and I am just learning them about.

Comment: I also saw somewhere about .something like [..., None] then adds a one on the shape. Is this also applicable? I have forgotten where I saw it and if it really is related to shape.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Most of the problem arises due to dimension incompatibility. Your array is flattened one (without any rows) that's why shape is (2,) you can reshape it. Check the updated answer.

Comment: but that `[..., None]` will give you `array([[2],
       [1]])` although the shape is the same. But it won't match with your rndm array element.

Comment: Saw your edited post, I tried reshaping the values (now, (2, 1)) but I am still getting the same error. Would there be a chance the error is coming from rndm itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215316/discussion-between-pygirl-and-acee).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.append` to add an array to the end of another array. The problem here is that `numpy.append` flattens the array first, ie. `numpy.append([1 0], [0 1])` is `[1 0 0 1]`. See [the numpy docs on `.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Comment: It is because rndm is a numpy array. So would it be better to make it as list then append those values?

Comment: The reason why it is appending like that because shape of those two are (2,) They are flattened that's why you will get that answer only but if you have shape like this (2,1) then  you can append row wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordinary list appending to generate the desired nested list structure:

```
rndm = [[0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1]
        ]

par_1 = [[1, 0]]
par_2 = [[0, 0]]
ch1 = [[1, 1]]
ch2 = [[0, 1]]

new_rndm = []

new_rndm.append(par_1)
new_rndm.append(par_2)
new_rndm.append(ch1)
new_rndm.append(ch2)

new_rndm = [i for k in new_rndm for i in k]

for data in new_rndm:
    rndm.append(data)

for data in rndm:
    print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[0, 1]
```